# Does exists a portable feed reader based on Google Reader?

Tags: windows, feed-reader

I am looking for a portable (can be installed on a USB key) feed reader based on Google Reader database.

I am using FeedDemon now, but unfortunately is not portable and Firefox Portable + Google Reader is not an option because I have too many feeds and I don't like Google Reader web interface.

Using the Windows OS.

Comment: FeedDemon is portable : just copy your directory 
*\Program Files\Feeddemon
in your USB key and run ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use FEED DEMON 3.0 
http://www.newsgator.com/download/FeedDemon/FeedDemonInstall.exe
which is GoogleReader sync.

Otherwise GREATNEWS 
http://curiostudio.com/dist/GreatNews.zip
which is a very friendly RSS reader but not Google Reader sync.

Hope this may help you

Comment: @ricciolo
FeedDemon is a really nice software, unfortunately it is not portable yet.

Answer (score 0):

[SE-RssTools](http://www.se-soft.com/) is a free and very simple portable RSS Reader. Just launch the program and read your favorite RSS feeds anywhere.

Comment: it seems nice but it seems also not Google Reader synchronizable

Comment: yes............... :-(